# How to make landscape to only one screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The home screen of my application is in landscape and have a background music. So in initstate i have implemented the screen as landscape, with music

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);

    _assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
    AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(
      Audio("assets/audio/bgm.mp3"),
      autoStart: true,
      showNotification: true,
    );
    _assetsAudioPlayer!.playOrPause();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    _assetsAudioPlayer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
```

All of this should only be contained in home Screen itself, i don't want it to pass to anyother screens.  But the music and the orientation are passed to the next screen. How can i contain it only to home screen.?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check dispose function is called? Perhaps deactive function is called instead of dispose.

If the problem is that, you can do your logic in deactivate function like:

```
  @override
  void deactivate() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    _assetsAudioPlayer = null;
    super.deactivate();
  }
```

Why deactivate method is called instead of dispose function :

> A typical situation where deactivate is called but not dispose,is when
> moving widgets in the widget tree using a GlobalKey.

Comment: I've tried with deactivate. it still shows the same issue. But when trying with Navigator.pushReplacementName, The orientation changes back to portrait. But the music keeps playing without deativating

Comment: Oh, because you set wrong audioplayer null. After this line _assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer(); you started the music with another instance of AssetsAudioPlayer not with _assetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open